# derivative of $\frac{2}{3}x^{3-e}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponentiation

> Find the derivative:$\;\;\;\;\;\;\dfrac{2}{3}x^{3-e}$

I am not sure how to solve this problem. My try:

$\ln y=\dfrac{2}{3}(3-e)\ln x$
$\dfrac{1}{y}\times y\;'=\dfrac{2}{3}(3-e)\dfrac{1}{x}$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. The answer is $\dfrac{2}{3}x^{2-e}(e-3)$ and I don't see how to arrive at that answer.

Comment: $\frac{2}{3}x^{3-e} = \frac{2}{3} x^3 x^{-e}$ and use the [product rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule).

Comment: Forget the concrete values, and see that it is $c\cdot x^\alpha$ for some constants $c$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: Your sure the answer has a factor e-3, not 3-e?

Comment: You know how to get the derivative of $8x^5$? This is just the same, but with $\frac23$ instead of $8$ and $(3-e)$ instead of $5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f\colon\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, with $f(x)=\frac{2}{3}x^{3-e}$, then
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}=
\frac{2}{3}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\Big(x^{3-e}\Big)
=
\frac{2}{3}(3-e)x^{3-e-1}
=
\frac{2(3-e)}{3}x^{2-e}
$$

Answer (score 0):

we have $y=\frac{2}{3}x^{3-e}$ taking the logarithm of both sides we get
$\ln(y)=\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)+(3-e)\ln(x)$ differentiating with respect to $x$
we find
$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{3-e}{x}$
this is equivalent to
$y'=\frac{3-e}{x}\frac{2}{3}x^{3-e}$